# How to change 8th position no to 0 in a 32 bit integer

Tags: bit-manipulation

Some one asked me this to how you can change/replace 8th position number to 0 in a 32 bit integer,Can I use left or right shift or what else any suggestion would be helpful.

This is not duplicate as far I am concerned with my specific problem for replacing a bit with 0, where as [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit) on this link it is too broad from me related to this problem.

Comment: Ask your teacher to explain if you're having difficulties with your homework. If that *some one* was not your teacher, then tell them you don't know.

Comment: I am expecting a suggestion to solve this

Comment: You are expecting us to do your homework. Some expectations lead to disappointment, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I have some reference, What should I read to solve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/62576

Comment: I am going through with this but their is a confusion:number ^= (-x ^ number) & (1UL << n);

Bit n will be set if x is 1, and cleared if x is 0. If x has some other value, you get garbage. x = !!x will booleanize it to 0 or 1.  This can set 1 only not 0

Comment: Ask your teacher to explain if you're having difficulties with your homework. They are being paid to teach you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binaryNum = binaryNum & ~ (1u << 7)
```

here binaryNum is your binary representation of number.

7(7 because it starts from 0) is the ith position where you wants to change.